# Ansible: removing hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I know that one can add host with the following task:

```
- name: Add new instance to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: '{{ item.public_ip }}'
    groupname: "tag_Name_api_production"
  with_items: ec2.instances
```

But I can't seem to find a way to remove a host from inventory. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: it didn't add the host inside the inventory but create dynamic group on the fly. you want to remove from the inventory?

Comment: Please describe your use case

Comment: It seems, that you can't do this. And do you really need this? It is dynamic inventory, so the main idea is to filter hosts beforehand, but not to remove them later

Comment: If you need to remove some hosts, I would suggest adding them to groups, and than running play excluding these groups, e. g. `hosts: '!databases'`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003420/reload-ansibles-dynamic-inventory. Using Ansible 2 you may do `- meta: refresh_inventory`

Comment: I'd better consider answering question

Comment: What was the use case? I have a similar use case where I am going to remove a failed host from execution but keep the playbook running for the rest.

Comment: @MikeD the use case was to remove hosts from inventory during blue/green deployments. Inventory was described with the dynamic inventory ec2.py script (based on the server name tag). Updating that tag did not update the inventory.

Comment: @cscan I was able to do this by adding the new target hosts to a group at runtime using either [group_by](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_by_module.html) or [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) modules. It's not clear in selected answer if that was the recommended solution but doing this all at runtime was my goal.

Comment: @MikeD that is what I ended up doing as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems, that you can't do this using Ansible 2. There is no such a module called `remove_host` or another one.

However, using Ansible 2 you can refresh your inventory mid-play:

```
- meta: refresh_inventory
```

[Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012534/4175647)

Another idea might be to filter hosts beforehand. Try adding them to group, and then excluding this group in a play lately, e.g. :

```
- hosts: '!databases'
```

Comment: I'm not sure when it changed, but when using ansible 2.14.1 it appears `refresh_inventory` no longer clears the inventory on refresh.

Comment: After more searching, I found that Ansible 2.14 no longer fully clears the inventory when using `refresh_inventory`: hosts previously added using `add_host` are preserved. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/77944.

Answer (score 3):

You can just stop the play for those hosts:

```
- name: Remove unwanted hosts from play_hosts
  meta: end_host
  when: unwanted
```

This assumes, of course, that the `unwanted` variable exists on all the hosts and is set properly.

Comment: This worked. It was a bit slow as the starting host group has over 500 members that Ansible has to loop through to check the condition, but it doesn't pollute my play log with hundreds of `skipped` lines as with using plain old `when:`. It's a decent enough compromise, if slower than I'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Can not removing hosts, but can choose to run on the new created group.

```yaml
- name: kubectl
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: nextcloud
      ansible_connection: kubectl
      ansible_kubectl_context: cluster
      ansible_kubectl_namespace: default
      ansible_kubectl_pod: nextcloud-75fc7f5c6f-hxrq6
      groupname: "pods"

# only run on pods
- hosts: pods
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - raw: pwd
    register: raw_result
  - debug:
      msg: "{{raw_result.stdout_lines[0]}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

We typically do it like this in a playbook using multiple `hosts:` sections.

```
- hosts: auth:!ocp
  roles:
    - ntp-server

- hosts: all:!auth:!ocp
  roles:
    - ntp-client
```

This will remove the groups of hosts from consideration via the `!group` mechanism. Specifically here in the 1st block we're removing the `!ocp` group and in the 2nd we're removing both the `!auth` and `!ocp` groups.

#### References

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem. I have tests which run `converge` for a given playbook (which I can't modify), and then I need to run the same playbook with smaller set of hosts in the group.

My solution is:

Let's say you have group `target` you want to make smaller.

1. Put smallest number of hosts in the `target` group.
2. Put additional hosts into `target_addon` group.

```yaml
- hosts: target_addon
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
        groups: [target]

- import_playbook: converge.yaml  # uses group `target` with added hosts

# Removing hosts added from target_addon group from group target by reloading inventory
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - meta: refresh_inventory

- import_playbook: converge.yaml  # uses group `target` without added hosts
```