# Ansible dynamic inventory refresh

Tags: dynamic, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have created a simple dynamic inventory python which prints JSON to standard output mentioned below, but Ansible inventory does not refresh.

Command: `ansible-playbook playbooks/deploy.yaml -i playbook/inventory_test.py`

Inventory JSON:

```
{
    'python_hosts': {
        'hosts': ['10.220.21.122', '10.220.21.278'],
        'vars': {
            'ansible_ssh_user': 'projectuser',
        }
    },
    '_meta': {
        'hostvars': {
            '10.220.21.122': {
                'host_specific_var': 'testhost'
            },
            '10.220.21.278': {
                'host_specific_var': 'towerhost'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: test
    script: ./inventory_test.py

  - name: Refresh inventory
    meta: refresh_inventory

  - name: print new inventory
    debug:
      var: groups
```

But inventory still does not refresh automatically.

Ansible version is 2.6.4

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the cache...
Go to ~/.ansible/tmp and delete inventory_test.cache file.

Also, [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34012534/1573395) helpful answer if you able edit playbook...